# What is causing my scripts to be requested twice while using Modernizr.load (yepnope.js)

Tags: javascript, modernizr, dynamic-script-loading, yepnope

I am using [yepnope.js](http://yepnopejs.com/) to load javascript files dynamically,and I've noticed that my scripts appear to be loaded twice according to Firebug and Webkit Inspector.

The problem is that in Firebug's Net panel (Firefox 4 latest), their response is a `200`, not a `304`. It seems to be slower than in Chrome.

I have uploaded [this video](http://screencast.com/t/G4nxKkGYVDEa) showing the issue. You can see how the files `jquery-1.6.1.min.js` and `libs.js` are loaded an extra time.

The code I am using to do this is the following, simplified:

```
Modernizr.load({
                load: ['jquery-1.6.1.min.js', 'libs.js'],
                complete: function () {
                    console.log("loaded");
                }
});
```

`Modernizr.load()` is `yepnope()`.

Comment: @HappyDeveloper Have a look at yepnopejs' site - it also does the same. Perhaps it is how it works. But, it appears to download twice?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's a note about this in their documentation:

From http://yepnopejs.com/

> I'm seeing two requests in my dev
>   tools, why is it loading everything
>   twice?
>
> Depending on your browser and
>   your server this could mean a couple
>   different things. Due to the nature of
>   how yepnope works, there are two
>   requests made for every file. The
>   first request is to load the resource
>   into the cache and the second request
>   is to execute it (but since it's in
>   the cache, it should execute
>   immediately). Seeing two requests is
>   pretty normal as long as the second
>   request is cached. If you notice that
>   the second request isn't cached (and
>   your script load times are doubling),
>   then make sure you are sending the
>   correct cache headers to allow the
>   caching of your scripts. This is vital
>   to yepnope. It will not work without
>   proper caching enabled. We actually
>   test to make sure things aren't loaded
>   twice in our test suite, so if you
>   think we may have a bug in your
>   browser regarding double loading, we
>   encourage you to run the test suite to
>   see if the double loading test passes.

Comment: I realised this afterwards, forgive my ignorance, and thank you for your answer.

Comment: I still don't understand why they had to make it this way. Facebook's bootloader thing doesn't have such issue with loading the file twice..

Comment: What's the best 'drop-in' replacement if 2 requests in the network activity is a problem?