# yepnope loading js twice

Tags: javascript, firebug, yepnope

I am trying to load a JS file using [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) using the below code:

```
yepnope({
    load: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>static/js/highlight.min.js',
    complete: function()
    {
        hljs.tabReplace = '    ';
        hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    }
});
```

However when I look in firebug to see what is loading it shows that it is being loaded twice. Am I doing anything wrong because I am confused?

[image]

Comment: You should probably delete the question.

Comment: What about marking my answer as accepted as it might help others coming to the site? I can do that tomorrow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should have really looked harder for existing [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400067/what-is-causing-my-scripts-to-be-requested-twice-while-using-modernizr-load-yep) before posting.

> I'm seeing two requests in my dev tools, why is it loading everything twice?
>
> Depending on your browser and your server this could mean a couple
>   different things. Due to the nature of how yepnope works, there are
>   two requests made for every file. The first request is to load the
>   resource into the cache and the second request is to execute it (but
>   since it's in the cache, it should execute immediately). Seeing two
>   requests is pretty normal as long as the second request is cached. If
>   you notice that the second request isn't cached (and your script load
>   times are doubling), then make sure you are sending the correct cache
>   headers to allow the caching of your scripts. This is vital to
>   yepnope. It will not work without proper caching enabled. We actually
>   test to make sure things aren't loaded twice in our test suite, so if
>   you think we may have a bug in your browser regarding double loading,
>   we encourage you to run the test suite to see if the double loading
>   test passes.